# Ext.tree.Panel store: keep scrollbar position after load/reload

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I'm using Ext.tree.Panel of ExtJS 4.2.1. I would like to know  if there is a way to preserve the position of the scrollbar after a data load (i.e. setRootNode(), loadData()). Right now, after the data is loaded, the scrollbar position is reset to the top.

Thanks in advance for any lead on this.

Comment: Try adding the preserveScrollOnRefresh : true config to your tree once.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

```
viewConfig: {
        preserveScrollOnReload: true
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I noticed that "preserveScrollOnReload" does not work in Ext.tree.panel.

I resolved with `cacheScrollValues`. Example:

```
function updateNodes(nodes) {
        var restoreScroll = App.yourGrid.el.cacheScrollValues();
        var sto = App.yourGrid.getStore();
        sto.setRootNode(nodes);
        restoreScroll();
```

PS: I'm also using ext 4.2.1.

Answer (score -1):

Hi try adding the following code once to your tree panel for scroll preserving.

For more information on this [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.view.AbstractView-cfg-preserveScrollOnRefresh) from Sencha docs

```
  viewConfig: {
        preserveScrollOnRefresh: true
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: i actually tried that before i posted my question. but i tried again and it is not working. perhaps the Ext.tree.Panel.store.setRootNode() is ignoring that config?